# How to Mock recursive function

Tags: junit, powermock

When I test a method the inner of the method invokes itself and another method that is in the same class. I use a partial mock to specify the other method's return value but how do I specify the first method's return value?

Comment: In addition to what dkatzel states, it is generally poor practice to mock the class under test.

Comment: In addition, there is near zero useful information in that question to provide a useful response. Sample code / output / stacktraces go a long way. Help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are mocking the method, then it is no longer recursive - because the mock will only return the final return value that would be returned after recursion.

If you want to test the recursive function, then don't mock the recursive method.

Your explanation is a little unclear, but perhaps just mocking the other method that is called is sufficient for your test.  You can make sure that other method gets called with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

lets try `returnsMany` in mockk:

`coEvery{ mockEntity.recursiveMethod()}.returnsMany(value1, value2,...)`

The first call recursiveMethod() will return value1, then the second call return value2,...

Handle your recursive flow in the right way